# async and await function Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, ipfs

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMlo9_wfKYU) to upload files into IPFS using Node.js, but I had a problem which doesn't appear in the tutorial! 
It is related to with Async and await function, I can't make this statement

```
const fileHash = fileAdded[0].hash;
```

I tried with await

```
const fileAdded = await ipfs.add({path: Name, content: file});
```

but unfortunately, I got an error which is (hash undefined).

I tried with a callback function, but I'm not sure about my way because (fileAdded) variable didn't give me any answer and also it was undefined,

this is a full code:

```
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const fs= require('fs');

const ipfs = new ipfsClient({host: 'localhost', port: '5001', protocol: 'http'});
const app= express();
var hash = require('hash');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home');
});

app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
    const f= req.files.file;
    const Name = req.files.file.name;
    const filePath ="files/"+ Name;

    f.mv(filePath,async(err)=>{

        if(err){
            console.log("error failed to download a file");
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }

        const fileh = await addFile(Name,filePath);

        fs.unlink(filePath, (err)=>{
            if(err) console.log("error");
        });

        res.render('upload',{Name,fileh});
    });
});

const addFile= async(Name,filePath)=> {
    const file=fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    const fileAdded = await ipfs.add({path: Name, content: file});

    const fileHash = fileAdded[0].hash;

    return fileHash;
};

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server is listen");
});
```

this is the error appears:

[image: error message] 
i write a callback function like that :

```
const addFile= async(Name,filePath)=> {
const file=fs.readFileSync(filePath);


const fileAdded = await ipfs.add({path: Name, content: file},(err,res)=>{
    if(err)
    console.log(err);


const fileHash = fileAdded[0].hash;

return fileHash;});};
```

but the value of fileAdded and fileHash was undefined.

after i use this code from @Always Learning :

```
  const addFile= async(Name,filePath)=> {
  const file=fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const hashes = [];
  const filesAdded = ipfs.add({path: Name, content: file});
  for await (const result of filesAdded) {
    hashes.push(result.hash);
    console.log(result.hash);
    console.log(result);

  }

  return hashes; // if you know it's just one for example
};
```

It gave me an information of a file, but hash does not work as it gave me undefined, I want extract just a hash like this "QmRndAYkvH3D2qhmYfaAZvWT6MDi4NiJPbzJor3EL87rrb"

[image: result]

Comment: The easiest way to understand what's happening is putting a breakpoint in your favorite debugging-enabled ide after the fileAdded variable to see what's actually in it.

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: yes, i update the question @dev

Comment: I see no try/catch block, so, if the promise returns as rejected, you have no way of catching that

Comment: even when i use try/catch block always the result get to reject, but i don't know why this error happen. @balexandre

Comment: now i know what is happen but i do not know why, but thanks for your help i will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ipfs.add()` returns an async-iterable object, you need to use `for async` to go through it like this:

```
const addFile= async(Name,filePath)=> {
  const file=fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const hashes = [];
  const filesAdded = ipfs.add({path: Name, content: file});
  for await (const result of filesAdded) {
    if (result.hash) {
      hashes.push(result.hash);
    } else if (result.cid) {
      hashes.push(result.cid.multihash); // guessing here - might be another part of the cid object
    } else {
      console.log("No hash found in",result);
    }
  }

  return hashes[0]; // if you know it's just one for example
};
```

Comment: thank a lot for helping, but even this solution it gave undefined value, i don't know why.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the newer attempt also?

Comment: Note that `hash` isn’t always part of the result object. Add `console.log(result)` in the loop to see what the object looks like. It’s possible that `result.hash` really is undefined

Comment: yes "result" works,  thanks a lot but "hash" does not work yet, i update the question if you can see. @Always Learning

Comment: The hash you want seems to be in `result.cid` so you can get it from there

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to handle different hash types in the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this:

```
const fileHash = fileAdded[0].hash;
```

into this:

```
const fileHash = fileAdded.hash;
```

(so remove `[0]`).

This worked for me: it has to do with the libraries.